# Spring Integration Java DSL: The Http.outboundGateway with the HttpMethod.PATCH is not working

Tags: spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

When the Spring Integration does the `Http.outboundGateway` call with the `HttpMethod.PATCH` operation there comes the exception:

```
Caused by: java.net.ProtocolException: Invalid HTTP method: PATCH
at java.base/java.net.HttpURLConnection.setRequestMethod(HttpURLConnection.java:487)
at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.setRequestMethod(HttpURLConnection.java:569)
at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.setRequestMethod(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:365)
at org.springframework.http.client.SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory.prepareConnection(SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory.java:226)
at org.springframework.http.client.SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory.createRequest(SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory.java:146)
at org.springframework.http.client.support.HttpAccessor.createRequest(HttpAccessor.java:87)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:719)
```

This is the problem in the Java class `HttpURLConnection`, because it doesn't support the PATCH operation.

I must use the `PATCH` method. What are the best ways to handle this situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `RestTemplate` by default uses a `SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory` based on the Java `HttpURLConnection`. Consider to use some other `ClientHttpRequestFactory`, e.g. `HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory`. When you declare such a bean you can inject it into the `Http.outboundGateway().requestFactory()`:

```
/**
 * Set the {@link ClientHttpRequestFactory} for the underlying {@link RestTemplate}.
 * @param requestFactory The request factory.
 * @return the spec
 */
public HttpMessageHandlerSpec requestFactory(ClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory) {
```